# unexpected results with square brackets in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a database with a Table named `PaymentReciept` I was playing around and found some unexpected results from a simple select all query.

```
// Return 3139 rows
select * from PaymentReciept

// Return 3139 rows
select * from dbo.PaymentReciept 

// Return 0 rows
select * from [dbo.PaymentReciept]
```

I don't understand why the query with square brackets return no results. I know that square brackets are used as delimiters for identifiers that use some special character or a keyword.

Can someone kindly explain to me what's going on or direct me to some article or a book where I can learn more about this behavior.

Comment: One should also point out the reason for down vote when down voting a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[dbo.PaymentReciept]`

Means that SQL is querying a table whose name is dbo.PaymentReceipt

whereas

`dbo.PaymentReciept` and `PaymentReciept` means that SQL is querying a table called `PaymentReceipt` in the schema `dbo`.

To use square brackets correctly, use:

`[dbo].[PaymentReciept]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. But if SQL is querying a table named `dbo.PaymentReceipt` then why it is not returning an object not found error as there is no table named `dbo.PaymentReceipt`.?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Maybe it is created..  try running `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%PaymentReceipts `

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets should be placed around schema name (`dbo`) and the table name (`PaymentReciept`), as these two are *separate* objects:

```
select * from [dbo].[PaymentReciept]
```